# PHP mvc routing issue with links

Tags: php, url

I'm just beginning with PHP, and started with YouTube tutorial about  [mvc](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD).
All went well, but when I started to develop my own application I encountered a problem with routing (I think).

My base application has URL: localhost/mvc/public/.

With the tutorial I created a class which starts a default home controller and index action when those are not specified. So localhost/mvc/public/ is equivalent to localhost/mvc/public/home/index.

In my view I have:

```
<p>You need to <a href="profile/login">log in</a> or <a href="profile/register">register</a></p>
```

So when I start with url localhost/mvc/public/ and then click on a link, it goes to localhost/mvc/public/profile/login and everything works fine.
But if I write url localhost/mvc/public/home/index and then click a link I go to localhost/mvc/public/home/profile/index which obviously doesn't work.
So my question is - how to solve this problem?

If someone is interested, I can post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`profile/register` is a relative path, so it is added to the path you already had. Because `/home/index` doesn't have a trailing `/`, the browser assumes `home` is the path and `index` is a file or resource name, so `home` is kept and `profile/register` is added to it.

Solution: change the paths to `/profile/register` (with a leading `/`) in your links. The `/` at the beginning tells the browser to add the path after the bare domain name, instead of choosing a path relative to the current one.

Probably better: add a 'basepath' setting to your application by which it knows what the base path is. In your code you can use this base path when generating paths, for instance:

```
<a href="<?=$basepath?>profile/register">
```

If you installed the application in the root, you can set basepath to `/`. In your case, you could set it to `/mvc/public/`.

Instead of a variable, you can create a function for it too to wrap the setting. If you search for "CodeIgniter base path" you will find plenty of examples of how CodeIgniter (a popular MVC framework) handles this.

Comment: Ha, didn't know about that. But now it goes to localhost/profile/register instead of localhost/mvc/public/profile/register

Comment: Good point. I think the best way to solve that is to add a path setting. Most web applications have settings like that. It's because relative paths cause troubles (as you have noticed), and without such a setting, it's hard to determine the right path.